# Nesting VLOOKUP functions

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to nest the `VLOOKUP` function as shown below

```
=VLOOKUP(D21, VLOOKUP(B21, PCLIST, 3, FALSE), 2, FALSE)
```

The nested `VLOOKUP` is accessing `PCLIST` which is a list of names of named spaces that coordinate with `B21`.

By itself this expression evaluates as expected.

The outside `VLOOKUP` function will evaluate fine if I specifically name the named space I want to look.

It seems like there is an error somewhere when evaluating the nested `VLOOKUP` as a named range.

I am receiving the #VALUE! error

Comment: `VLOOKUP` returns a *single value*, not a range. No surprise the outer `VLOOKUP` causes an error.

Comment: The single value returned by the nested lookup is a name that references a named region. Let's say it returns X. I have defined X to be a range of values that I want the outside VLOOKUp to reference. Is this not the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Your inner `vlookup()` is returning the name of a named range which is what you are trying to search with your outer `vlookup()`.

The problem is that the outer `vlookup()` is seeing the return from the inner `vlookup()` as a string, and so it's erroring out. To turn a string into a range in Excel we use the `Indirect()` formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(D21, Indirect(VLOOKUP(B21, PCLIST, 3, FALSE)), 2, FALSE)
```

Comment: Beat me by 8 seconds. 8P

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @ScottCraner That's unusual. It's almost always the other way around </furiously typing>